# MailKit not sending emails in windows service(ASP NET Core 3.x)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a mailing service. It successfully sends messages from debug. But not sending from the service. I configure the service as Network service, but this is nit working. Am I configuring the service incorrectly? I used this question [Mailkit imapclient working with console application but not working as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693726/mailkit-imapclient-working-with-console-application-but-not-working-as-windows-s)

Comment: What account is the service using?  The service is running with a different user account that the account you are using to test.  A service probably doesn't have any environmental variables so that is why it is failing.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: On the same machine?  Where does the logger error message go?  In task manager to you see the application running?  Are you running service as Admin? If you do not run as Admin the service is running as System which doesn't have any environmental variables.  So one guess is the service is getting an exception when writing to the logger.  The code has following line : "client = new ImapClient (new ProtocolLogger (Console.OpenStandardError ()));" So you may want to have logger write to a file (not standard output) that service has permission to write.

Comment: If code worked as Core 2.0 the see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#aspnet-core-30

Comment: @jdweng, Thank! You helped me. It is working! The service was not started by my user. Could you return the comment I marked in Answers?